# google places auto complete index.es.js:28 Refused to load the script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-places-autocomplete

Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=__googleMapsCallback&key=API_KEY_HERE&libraries=places' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsa

putting meta tags not worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Content Security Policy Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/content-security-policy), you may need to [Allowlist CSP](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/content-security-policy#allowlist_csp) to address this issue.

See also the [Content Security Policy update (March 21, 2022 - May 2023)](https://developers.google.com/maps/deprecations#content-security-policy-update) in case you may need to make additional changes in the near future.